# How to delete shared preferences data from App in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How do I delete SharedPreferences data for my application?

I'm creating an application that uses a lot of web services to sync data. For testing purposes, I need to wipe out some SharedPreferences values when I restart the app.

Answer (score 994, accepted):

To remove specific values: [SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) followed by a `commit()`

To remove them all `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()`

If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from your application's main thread, consider using `apply()` instead.

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", 0).edit().clear().commit(); //remove all your prefs :)

Comment: @yoshi there is definitely a remove() as well as a clear().  You use remove() to remove specific preferences, you use clear() to remove them all.  The original question wasn't clear if they needed to remove them all or not.

Comment: Clearing the preferences file does not appear to actually delete it. In my own tests by watching the "Data" usage listed in the App Info panel, creating a new SharedPreference file adds 4KB to this value but using editor.clear().commit() does not reduce the number.

Comment: @rubdottocom Why don't you put your comment as a separate answer?

Comment: @technophyle wow this comment has more than hundred votes! I added the answer below with a slightly improvement ;-)

Comment: @rubdottocom better using .apply() instead of .commit()

Comment: In kotlin that is sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply()

Answer (score 215):

My solution:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
preferences.edit().remove("text").commit();
```

Comment: Does that remove the variable TEXT only?

Comment: @SiKni8 Yes, that removes only the key/value pair with key `"text"`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work because it's been a while but thank you for the response :)

Comment: You saved my absolute sanity. :P THANK YOU. I was trying to clear the prefs for one element of an object at a time, and this works beautifully.

Comment: Consider using apply() instead of commit() to do the task in a background thread.

Answer (score 156):

Removing all preferences:

```java
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

Removing single preference:

```java
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.edit().remove("KeyName").commit();
```

Comment: What will be the `KeyName`?

Comment: How to delete the entire preference file, not just the preferences inside the file?

Comment: Use apply() instead of commit() to do the task in a background thread. commit() blocks and write data to storage instantly. apply() is asynchronous.

Answer (score 78):

If it's not necessary to be removed every time, you can remove it manually from:

> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> (choose your app)
>   -> Clear data or Uninstall

Newer versions of Android:

> Settings -> Applications -> (choose your app) -> Storage -> Clear data
>   and Clear cache

Comment: can we do this things programmatic.

Comment: @amity The other answer does it programatically.

Comment: @amity - Some of us needed this answer. I was unsure how to remove SharedPrefs on an Android Emulator so that I could continue testing my code.

Comment: Not there in android studio 2.2.2 10/18/2016.

Comment: Thanks, was just looking for deleting this way.

Answer (score 28):

Deleting Android Shared Preferences in one line :-)

```
context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

Or `apply` for non-blocking asynchronous operation:

```
this.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", 0).edit().clear().apply();
```

Comment: Best solution for me. There are few cases when synchronous is neccesary for sharedpreferences content.

Answer (score 25):

Seems that all solution is not completely working or out-dead

to clear all SharedPreferences in an Activity

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().clear().apply();
```

Call this from the Main Activity after onCreate

note* i used `.apply()` instead of `.commit()`, you are free to choose commit();

Comment: exactly what I want. Thanks it clears all default preferences

Answer (score 17):

As of API 24 (Nougat) you can just do:

```
context.deleteSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS");
```

However, there is no backward compatibility, so if you're supporting anything less than 24, stick with:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply();
```

Answer (score 15):

In the class definitions:

```
private static final String PREFERENCES = "shared_prefs";

private static final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Inside the class:

```
public static void deleteAllSharedPrefs(){
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the adb shell to do this even without a rooted phone. The only catch is that the app must be debuggable.

```
run-as <your package name> <command>
```

For example:

```
run-as com.asdf.blah rm /data/data/com.asdf.blah/databases/myDB.db
```

Alternatively, you can just do the above but without the command which will direct you to the app package root and allow you to execute more commands in the app's context.

Comment: +1 for the useful tip on `run-as`. You'd think I would have found this after 3 yrs...

Comment: This isn't the Sharedpreferences, it's the sqlite database

Answer (score 11):

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("clear_cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 11):

Clear them all:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().apply()
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also just manually uninstall your app using your device. Then when you re-install your app, shared preferences have been reset.

Comment: Thanks -  i did not want to programmatically remove sharedPreferences so this worked for me.

Comment: On my device I have the option to "clear data" on the uninstall option, which worked for me and removed the need to reinstall my app.

Answer (score 9):

**For Kotlin users it is fairly easy:**

```
val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 sharedPref.edit().clear().apply()
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fake", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
edit.clear().commit();
```

Answer (score 7):

If it is for your testing. You can use adb commands.

```
adb shell pm clear <package name>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always do it programmatically as suggested by the other answers over here. But for development purpose, I find this `Plugin` very helpful as it speeds up my development significantly.

PLUGIN: **ADB Idea**

It provides you with features to **Clear App Data** and **Revoke Permission** from your Android Studio itself, just with click of a button.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To remove the key-value pairs from preference, you can easily do the following

```
getActivity().getSharedPreference().edit().remove("key").apply();
```

I have also developed a library for easy manipulation of shared preferences. You may find the following link

https://github.com/farruhha/SimplePrefs

Answer (score 5):

```
String prefTag = "someTag";
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext);
prefs.edit().remove(prefTag).commit();
```

This will delete the saved shared preferences with the name "someTag".

Answer (score 4):

To clear all SharedPreferences centrally from any class:

```
public static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}
```

And then from any class: (commit returns a Boolean where you can check whether your Preferences cleared or not)

```
Navigation.getEditor(this).clear().commit();
```

Or you can use apply; it returns void

```
Navigation.getEditor(this).clear().apply();
```

Answer (score 3):

- To remove a particular value,

**SharedPreferences.Editor remove(String key)** followed by a commit() or a apply()

- To remove all the values,

  **SharedPreferences.Editor clear()** followed by a commit() or a apply()

Answer (score 3):

The ***Kotlin ktx*** way to **clear all** preferences:

```
val prefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefsName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
prefs.edit(commit = true) {
    clear()
}
```

[Click here](https://alexzh.com/2018/11/12/guide-shared-preferences/) for all Shared preferences operations with examples

Answer (score 3):

One line of code in kotlin:

```
getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply()
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers work for me since I have many shared preferences keys.

Let's say you are running an Android Test instead of a unit test.

It is working for me loop and delete through all the **shared_prefs** files.

> @BeforeClass will run before all the tests and ActivityTestRule

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    File root = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile();
    String[] sharedPreferencesFileNames = new File(root, "shared_prefs").list();
    for (String fileName : sharedPreferencesFileNames) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(fileName.replace(".xml", ""), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName).delete();
```

I can delete file in shared preferences with it

Comment: All above solutions are wrong, only delete file is right one to delete shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

In Java:

```java
SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
myPrefs.edit().remove("my_key").apply();
```

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
val myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
myPrefs.edit().remove("my_key").apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin :

```
  var prefs2: SharedPreferences? = context!!.getSharedPreferences("loginFB", 0)
  prefs2!!.edit().remove("email").commit()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `preferences.edit().remove("key").commit()` to delete saved values from shared preferences.

Answer (score -2):

This is my ***`Kotlin`*** method:

```
      public fun clearAllSharedPrefs() {
            val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = MainApplication.applicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences("MY_CUSTOME_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            sharedPreferences.edit().clear()
            sharedPreferences.edit().apply()
        }
```

Answer (score -5):

Just did this this morning.  From a command prompt:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs
rm * // to remove all shared preference files
rm YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml // to remove a specific shared preference file
```

**NOTE**: This requires a rooted device such as the stock Android virtual devices, a Genymotion device, or an actual rooted handset/tablet, etc.

Comment: So whoever down voted this solution should maybe also explain why: You need a rooted phone to access `/data/data` directly!

Comment: You need to Remove the SharedPreferences form the Application and not the ADB Shell.It is done using: SharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();

Comment: Asked never said they wanted a no root solution. There is a technical error here though; because this method requires root, you have to run `su` after `adb shell` to open up a privileged shell.

Comment: Why was this downvoted so much? This is a useful answer and the one I was looking for.