# Android: reset all the SharedPreferences used by application to defaults

Tags: android, preferences, reset

In my app, preferences are organized by `SharedPreferences`. I need to perform reset to application defaults.

I know how to reset all values for particular `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
      "name_of_the_preferences_file",
      MODE_PRIVATE
      );

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

But the problem is that only preferences for one particular preferences "name_of_the_preferences_file" is reset. Of course, all the rest preferences are not affected.

So, how to achieve full defauls reset?

It would be good to get names of all the preferences files, to reset it one-by-one.

But ideally, I want programmatically destroy all application data. This could be the best variant.

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences

Comment: Thanks, but there is only the same solution as I stated in my question, but to remove all the settings I need to have root access, isn't it? So unfortunately I can't find the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer : see [Deleting shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences)

Edit : You stated "I need to perform reset to application defaults." and that link provides the solution: you didn't mention resetting all preferences of all apps.
You cannot erase preferences from other apps from your own app because sharedpreferences are stored in a file and your app won't have write rights to directories that contain these files

Comment: Of course I do NOT want to reset prefs for all the apps. This would be very bad wish. Each app can have several prefs files (in my example, pref file name is "name_of_the_preferences_file"). And I want to get all the names of these files for my app. (then I will be able to reset settings in each file)

Comment: You have to iterate over each shared pref & call clear() No other way

Comment: But how can I get list with all the prefs that my app created?

Comment: Oh that's your problem ? Why don't you use a single SharedPref. Instead of having Pref1, Pref2, Pref3, etc... with a bunch of keys you would have only one pref with jeys Pref1.*, Pref2.*

Comment: If there's no way to get list, then maybe I'll have to do so, thanks. But this seems to be poor that I can't get list with all the file names..

Comment: You may be over-using preferences a little bit, maybe Sqlite would be better. I don't know...