# Android Login Design and development - Approaches and best practices

Tags: android, authentication

Okay. I started developing an Android App for our enterprise web app. Just started the Login screen activity design.

This app is completely driven by RESTFul API.

I would like to understand how to develop login / logout feature in the application.
As far as I understand, there is no Session concept in the app world. Also, for the API, we need to send Username and Password with every request (Basic Auth). So apparently, we need to keep the login credentials somewhere in the local storage to send along with every request.

Here is what I understand from my basic Android knowledge.

When user enters login information and presses the button, we'll spin up a HTTP call to API. If login credentials are valid, then we'll have to store the credentials locally. Options are

1. SQLite
2. Shared Preferences. (I never used it. But I am assuming, we can use this)
3. Bundle (Not sure if this is an option)

Any other alternatives?

I want to make sure I follow the best practice, while not sacrificing from performance and architecture perspective.

And for the logout, I think I just need to wipe out the credentials stored locally and show login Activity.

Are there any different and better approaches?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest making use of the Android [Accounts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/package-summary.html) feature.

[This blog](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2) has a pretty good step by step guide on all the bits you need to put together.

The general idea is you supply the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) with the users username/password, and leave it up to the AccountManager to store them securely.

When you need an authentication token, you ask the AccountManager for one, and it will either return a cached token, or call back into your code (passing the username/password) and you make the call to your authentication service to get a fresh token.

Comment: I am confused about the 3rd para. When you store the data in Accounts, does it expire at sometime? That means, if the user is in the middle of the app, on some Activity, if Accounts does not give me U/P, I need to show the login screen to grab the U/P again?

Comment: @KevinRave He is taking about reusing access token from preferences

Comment: The username/password will not expire. The authentication token returned from your webservice can expire (on the server side), if this happens you need to inform the AccountManager that the token has expired and that will trigger the callback instructing you to get a fresh token

Comment: @JaiSoni, The access tokens aren't stored in preferences when using the AccountManager

Comment: There is no authtocken mechanism here. REST calls need U/P in the header (Basic Auth)

Comment: So when they click on Logout, I need to wipe out the account details from the AccoutManager?

Comment: Basic Auth doesn't fit perfectly well with the AccountManager, you could hack it in by saving your U/P where the AuthToken would naturally go (put U/P into KEY_AUTHTOKEN in your override of confirmCredentials.

Comment: Yes if they click Logout you can wipe the account details from the AccountManager, or delete the Account itself.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that AccountManager doesn't implicitly encrypt passwords and just stores them as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, there are three ways you can persist data in Android: SQLite, `SharedPreferences`, and reading/writing onto a file a la Java I/O. SQLite is optimal for relational data, but because you simply need to store the user's credentials, I recommend you use SharedPreferences. It seems to me like a simple key-value data model.

`SharedPreferences` are basically just an encapsulation of direct file I/O--that is, the underlying implementation is still file reading and writing, but simplified for key-value pairs. I don't know much about encryption, but you might have to handle that yourself before storing the password in a `SharedPreferences` object (also consider JaiSoni's suggestion: use an access token instead). Rest assured, however, that if you create the `SharedPreferences` and set it to `MODE_PRIVATE`, other apps won't have access to the shared prefs file.

I believe this is pretty much a standard implementation. If you look at this page, there's really only so much you can do: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

May I also point out that one of the complexities with direct file I/O is that you'll have to decide where you want to store the file--internal or external memory (e.g., SD card)--and hence check for its availability (not all devices have SD card slots, and sometimes internal memory is registered as external memory to the device). So just go with shared prefs.

For logging out, this might be useful: [Deleting shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences)

Comment: Thanks. I want to know, if this is a standard way of doing it. Or there are better ways to do it. About logout?

Answer (score 2):

I think storing password in app is bad idea, better approach is just make request with user credential at first time when user get login the server return an access token save this access token in `SharedPreferences` for rest of purpose like getting user detail use the token in request.
Session : Create your own class for maintain session. [Hackbook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook) is a good example for it.

Comment: Great suggestion. This will require them to modify the back-end, though, am I right? If the access token mechanism hasn't been implemented yet, that is.

Comment: @mattquiros Yes you will require web service that support access token

Comment: @mattquiros You are right. That's a Business logic change at the backend. That cannot be done at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to persist the login credential in a file or database? do you want to be automatically logged in after your app is restarted? if persistance is not necessary you can put the credentials into a static java member.

Comment: Is it accessible across the application, throughout the user session?

Comment: And not sure how you assign username and password to static members during run time?

Comment: It is accessable if you make it public. For details see [tutorial Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: How do you instantiate / assign values for static variables at run time?

Comment: Just a thought--if you make the static variables public, isn't that dangerous because other apps will have access to it? How about protected, instead of public or private?

Comment: @mattquiros the static variable is ony accessable within the same app. If you want single-sign-on for several apps the static member does not work