# SharedPreferences reset: Map size is not 0 after reset

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to delete my `SharedPreferences`, but it's not working: `size` is not set to 0 as I would expect.

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(name, mode);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
e.clear();
e.commit();
Map<String, ?> map = sp.getAll();
int size = map.size();
```

Any suggestions?

```
private static String name = "ABC_PREFS";
private static int mode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
```

Comment: `android`>`settings`>`applications`>`manage applications`>`your app`>`clear data` :)

Comment: I guess I should have said that I want to do this at runtime.

Comment: What is the mode you use to access the SharedPreferences?

Comment: What is in your `map` that you get from `getAll()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Everything that I have saved in the preferences previously.

Comment: Is that the exact code you're using? or are there any other calls in between?
Also, check what does the `commit()` calls returns. `true` or `false`

Comment: @Lablabla It is. Those 6 lines are just implemented in a `public void clearPreferences()` method. Well, there is 1 more line after `int size = ...` but that's just a Toast to read the `size` value. `commit()` returns `true`.

Comment: I copy and pasted it, and it works for me.. It shows size 0 after clearing.. weird..

Comment: Do you have more than one editor opening and modifying preferences at the same time? It sound like a race condition.

Comment: Please check(Answer 5) in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine from reading through it.   Are you sure that **context** variable is initialized properly?  Are other SharedPreferences variables pointing to the same file perhaps?

If these are not the problem, please consider taking a minimal sample app and paste this code in to see if it still fails.  It is easier to fix a problem like this with the complete app than with just a code snippet.

Comment: I think this is the closest I get to an answer I can use. I fixed it by using `App.getContext()` as context, where `App` is an Application class and the context in that is set at `onCreate()` in this class. So yes, it was a Context issue. Many points your way ;)

Answer (score 0):

[SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear%28%29) just removes only values of your preferences is that not enough for you? You can remove all your entries with [SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    for (String key: sp.getAll().keySet()) {
        e.remove(key);
    }
    e.commit();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can write size of map into shared preferences:

```
e.clear();
e.putInt("size", map.size());
e.commit();
```

To get size of map call:

```
int size = sp.getInt("size", 0);
```