# Shared Preferences in not being cleared,

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm unable to delete `SharedPreferences` from the app on click event.

Here is how I'm storing the value into UserInfoActivity `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences notificationCountSP = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor notificationEditor = perkBalance.edit();
notificationEditor.putString("notificationCount",notificationCountValue);
notificationEditor.commit();
```

And here is how I'm trying to clear all data in `SharedPreferences` from MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences clearNotificationSP = getSharedPreferences(
                "notificationCountSP", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = clearNotificationSP.edit();
editor.remove("notificationCount");
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Please tell what am I doing wrong with this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to call remove action on notificationEditor (in the first block)..   I guess, you edit two seperate preferences file.

Comment: Try to retrieve the SharedPrefences.Editor in the same way, and in the same context.

Comment: @hovanessyan do you something that I can look upon. I could not get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences notificationCountSP = PreferenceManager
                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor notificationEditor = notificationCountSP.edit();
notificationEditor.putString("notificationCount", notificationCountValue);
notificationEditor.commit();

notificationEditor.remove("notificationCount");
notificationEditor.commit();
```

or

```
SharedPreferences clearNotificationSP = getSharedPreferences("notification_prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = clearNotificationSP.edit();
editor.putString("notificationCount", notificationCountValue);
editor.commit();

editor.remove("notificationCount");
editor.commit();
```

First solution uses the default application preferences file, and the second a custom notification_prefs file.

Comment: Hey, one quick doubt here, after doing your second method, I'm trying to print the value of the `editor.remove("notificationCount");` and it is printing in the log. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` to store but retrieving from `getSharedPreferences("notificationCountSP")`. They are different files unless you set the default one to "notificationCountSP".

Comment: `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, resId, true)`, where resId is the resource ID of the preference file. If you are not willing to create your own pref file, you could just use `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("notificationCountSP", mode)` and store the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
SharedPreferences userPref = getSharedPreferences(
                                    MyActivity.SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: This is for storing the values right? How can I store and delete the values according to you.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences) might help you