# delete all sharedPreferences for my app when user signs out

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an android app with a number of activities, and a number of specific preference files that are created. When a user sign out of my app, I want to delete absolutely all shared preferences. Understand that I cannot use `context.getSharedPreferences("A_PREFS_FILE", 0).edit().clear().commit()` as that would only clear one specific file. I want to clear all the preference files associated with my app. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences

Comment: `clear()` is a non-static method, and therefore `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` would not work. All the other examples there are doing exactly what I specifically said I don't want to do. Also, following would be a null pointer: `Editor defaultPrefsPut;
 defaultPrefsPut.clear();
 defaultPrefsPut.commit();`

Comment: What's the problem with subsequently clearing every preference file, i.e. in a loop?

Answer (score 23):

By this way you can delete all the files at ones..
by clear() it will erase the data file still exist..

```
File sharedPreferenceFile = new File("/data/data/"+ getPackageName()+ "/shared_prefs/");
    File[] listFiles = sharedPreferenceFile.listFiles();
    for (File file : listFiles) {
        file.delete();
    }
```

Here it will returns the all the list of files then you can easily delete..

Comment: This is definitivly the right way to delete all shared preferences files.

But consider to use `context.getFilesDir().getPath()` instead of hard coding the path `"/data/data/"`

Comment: @YoracoGonzales `context.getFilesDir().getPath()` gives me `/data/user/0/{applicationId}/files` which is not equal to `/data/data/`

Comment: `context.filesDir.parentFile.absolutePath + File.separator + "shared_prefs"` did work. But who knows maybe it will not work on Samsung ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 11):

Simply put the following code, It works perfect for me.....

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CREDENTIALS", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: Consider using apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background.

```getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", 0).edit().clear().apply();```

Answer (score 3):

First you have to `clear` then next call `commit`
Try it:

```
SharedPreference.Editor pref = context.getSharedPreferences("A_PREFS_FILE", 0).edit();
pref.clear();
pref.commit();
```

Comment: what is A_PREFS_FILE

Comment: The question asked for `A_PREFS_FILE` so, You can write your preference name.

Answer (score 3):

Use the code below to delete a preference key:

```
prefs.edit().remove("YOURTAG1").commit();
prefs.edit().remove("YOURTAG2").commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences directory path : **Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + ActivateAccountActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs"**

Use "**for**" loop to delete all the files, like so :

```
File sprefs_directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs");
File[] files = filesirectory.listFiles();
for(File file : files) {
  file.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
public static void deleteAllDataInSharedPreference(Context context){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    context = null;
}

deleteAllDataInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a SharedPreference that keeps track of all associated files; then, in onPause or onStop, parse that value to SharedPreferences.Editor.clear().commit() each of them...then  delete that last one?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all Shared Preferences with e.g.

```
val sharedPreferenceFile = File("${application.dataDir.path}/shared_prefs/")
sharedPreferenceFile.listFiles()?.forEach(File::delete)
```