# Android Sharedpreferences Timelimit

Tags: android, timeout, sharedpreferences

In my android application I am using shared preference to remember some inputs so that whenver application get started user don't need to type the input every time.. now I need to logout the sharedpreference if the time of using the app is more than 24 hours.. Like in gmail something our login details will be remembered for 24 hours or something and after tha  it will be automatically logout...What change I need to do for that.. I am giving my code below..

SharedPreference for remembering

```
if (spl1.equals("English")  ) 
            {SharedPreferences setting = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editors = setting.edit();
                    editors.putString("lo", "lo");

                    editors.putString("fn", firstName);
                    editors.putString("mn",middleName);
                    editors.putString("ln",lastName);

                    editors.putString("dt",dates);
                    editors.putString("mt",months);
                    editors.putString("yrs",years);
                    //Passing exp no, heart no, lifepath number
                    editors.putLong("name11", sum11);
                    editors.putLong("name12", sum12);
                    editors.putLong("name10", sum10);

                    editors.commit();



                    Intent t = new Intent(FullExplanationEntry.this, TabLayoutActivityh.class);
}
```

logout

*

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.button04) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.remove("lo");
                    editor.commit();
                    finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: "now I need to logout the sharedpreference if the time of using the app is more than 24 hours", you mean you want to clear the values from sharedprefrences ?

Comment: exactly.. after 24 hrs.. automatically .. values need to be cleared

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is , store the last login time in sharedprefence using :-

```
editors.putLong("lastlogin", new Date().getTime());
```

and when users starts the app next time, get the lastlogin time and check whether its older than 24hrs , if yes then clear the data using :-

[Deleting shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences)

Comment: ya.. that good.. do u know how to check if the time is more than 24 hrs

Comment: u can calculate the difference between two dates and if it exceeds 24*60*60*1000 then its older than 24 hrs 
or u can refer this 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

Comment: I am glad that it was helpful !!

Answer (score 4):

You can add the system time also into the shared preference and then check for the same and compare the date from the **shared-preference** whenever the user launch the application or when the application comes to foreground.

If this exceeds more that your limit (24hrs) , just clear the **shared-preference**.