# Delete all shared preferences files

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `getPreferences()` method in different activities of my app. That means, Android create different files, one for each activity in which I am using that method.

I would like to clear all those files. Is there any way?
Now, I delete every single file in the shared_prefs directory of the app, but I would like a more "safety" solution.

```
File folder = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "shared_prefs" + File.separator);
                if (folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory()) {
                    String[] children = folder.list();
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                        new File(folder, children[i]).delete();
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting shared preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences)

Comment: do you want to clear data from preference file??

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", 0).edit().clear().commit(); //remove all your prefs

Comment: @RvdK In that way, I gotta check the name of the preference files and clear all of them, one by one. Is there any way to reset all the preferences in one shot?

Comment: @KrupaPatel clear data from all preference files, not just one.

Comment: I don't see any difference with clear each preference files as opposed to deleting each file individually. Furthermore deleting a file which you don't have created manually will likely create undefined behavior. E.g. what happens when your app is open and you delete such files.

Comment: This looks like a very good solution to me. Nothing wrong with it. The last `+ File.separator` is not needed. Nothing will go wrong. The app behaves as if it is newly installed.