# How to store/restore activity state when moving/navigating back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How can I save **activity state (B)** when moving to **previous activity (A)** and how to restore it's previous state when moving back (to activity B)?

**SCENARIO**

Content of activity B can be changed by user. After finishing work, performed changes can be **persisted** (e. g. saved to local DB). Before persisting, user may want to navigate back to previous activity. At this point, "work session" should be somehow saved **temporary in memory**. After returning back to activity B "work session" should be restored, so user can continue in work.

**APPROACHES**

Standard methods `onCreate(Bundle)` and `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` are used to restore/save activity state when device configuration changes (e. g. on rotate). As [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is not part of activity's life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)), this method does not get called on "back-press" when activity is destroyed (by default `finish()` is called). The same applies for  [onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). Obviously these methods alone are not sufficient to restore activity state after lefting an activity.

**Transfering bundle state between activities**

One way I can think of is to override `onBackPressed()` in such way it will start an `Intent` to previous activity A with bundle state `Intent#putExtras(Bundle)` of current activity B. When moving back, starting an `Intent` to activity B, this bundle state will be delivered back `Intent#putExtras(Bundle)` to restore the state of activity B. However this also require to override `onCreate(Bundle)` and `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` in A so bundle state of B would not be lost on configuration change before navigating back to B.

**Not finishing an activity on back-press + non-default launchMode**

Another way (more cleaner) is to override `onBackPressed()` so that it would start `Intent` to previous activity A without calling `finish()` of current activity B so activity B will hang in memory in paused state (waiting for resume). To resume activity B, manifest configuration `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` is required so android will use existing activity (paused B) instead of creating new one (B2) when navigating back to activity B (`startIntent(B.class)`).

**Details**: launchMode singleInstance creates [singleton activity in new task](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) (task = set of activities with the same group id i. e. [affinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff), normally app activities have the same affinity i. e. app = single task).

**Drawback**: **transition animations does not work with singleInstance mode**. It seems that singleInstance task may not be fully initialized at animation time. For more details: [Custom animation doesnt work on SingleInstance Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144203/custom-animation-doesnt-work-on-singleinstance-activity).

**Saving activity state to SharedPreferences**

Saving activity state to `SharedPreferences` on "back-press", restoring activity state from preferences in `onCreate(Bundle)` like in following link [Save activity state to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171320/save-the-state-when-back-button-is-pressed).

**Drawback**: unable to save `Bundle` state (only primitives: `putInt`, `putString`, ...).

**Others**

Some of the methods listed in [Share data between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities#answer-4878259) can be used. Answers from this link refers to [developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html) which is unfortunately broken. Here is an alternative source http://wing-linux.sourceforge.net/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html.

About sharing data via Application object:

- [Don't Store Data in the `Application` Object](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/),
- [Using the Android Application class to temporary persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data#answer-4209391).
- Based on [Application class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) documentation, using **static singletons** over `Application` is **more preferable**.

  > Base class for maintaining global application state. ...
  >
  > **Note**: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations,
  >   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
  >   way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register
  >   broadcast receivers), include Context.getApplicationContext() as a
  >   Context argument when invoking your singleton's getInstance() method.

It seems that putting data in `Application` object or *static singleton* is so far the **best solution** for this problem.

**QUESTION**

Is there any **build-in** solution for this (without need of overriding `onBackPressed()`)? For example saving activity on back-stack with it's state. If not, what is the **common pattern** to save activity state in such situation?

**RELATED POSTS** (just to link them with this post)

[How do I save temporary data on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294879/how-do-i-save-temporary-data-on-android)

Comment: Show us some code of your activity and you flow. It might help people to understand further

Comment: @UmarZaii I think the code is not required here, I'm looking for cleaner solution (if exists)

Comment: do you want to keep view states or data in activity?

Comment: by **"moving back"** , do you mean start activity B again ?

Comment: @Ali as you said

Comment: @savepopulation I want to keep view states.

Comment: is activityB is like settings? So that activityA will be refreshed according to the settings?

Comment: i think you should store  the state in local file `onPaused` , and read that file when start the activity again

Comment: @UmarZaii no they have no relation except A can start B and B can navigate back to A, what I want is to save "session state" of B so I can return back and continue in work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative way to handle this, you can map your view's states to a data structure and save it as an object notation (such as json) to your local and when your activity is created / re-created you can read your state from local and bind them with your views.

For more information and example, you can check `Spotify's` presentations and open source project which contains information about how they manage application's ui from apis. (I know it's not exactly what you're trying to do but you may find some tricks.)

If you need to save your data in your activities, you can use `Local Db` or `in-memory cache`.

Answer (score 0):

When you back out of an activity, the activity is not just destroyed programmatically, but also conceptually.  In other words, the user *expects* it to be gone.  We talk about saving activity state in situations where the activity object is destroyed but the user perceives that it still exists, such as during configuration changes or when it's in the background or backstack.

What you're trying to save is properly thought of as application state, not activity state.  As such, `SharedPreferences` is an appropriate place for it.  Whether it's the best solution is a matter of opinion and depends on your use case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for thoughts. I saw similar suggestion somewhere else, I think this solution is almost perfect, but with SharedPreferences I'm not able to save Bundle object (Fragment's state). Can you think of any other solution that is commonly used?

Comment: @matoni I don't know of a simple way to save an entire `Bundle`.  But I would suggest that each `Fragment` should be responsible for saving its own state, and question why it's in a `Bundle` in the first place.

Comment: I have activity where I can put content fragment. Fragment contains `ViewPager` which consists of pages (fragments). I need to save state of these pages. First though was to export state of the `ViewPager's` adapter (`adapter.saveState()` which returns `Bundle`). Unfortunately, bundle contains only identifiers of the pages (fragments) so this bundle can restore state of the `ViewPager` only if fragments are alive (e. g. on configuration change). It seems that I need to save pages on my own (maybe I will save them in string format so I would be able to  `SharedPreferences`).

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to store state (in any form) in static field of the activity? Maybe I'm asking stupid questions, but I can't find any relevant resource on this topic. The only thing I found was: [How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?](http://wing-linux.sourceforge.net/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html). As I can't find similar article on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com) I don't know whether It is out-dated or not.