# How to restore search results in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` X which indeed has a `RecyclerView`, X has a search view, I use the search view to search something and filter the `RecyclerView` into few rows. After the filtering, if user clicks on some row, it goes to another `fragment` say Y. From there if the user clicks back it comes back to X. My task is that X should persist the search results after this coming back. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Propertly override `onSaveInstanceState` in `Fragment` so that it will store search input - filter. Also override `onCreate` in such way it will apply saved filter on your `RecyclerView`.

Before navigating to another fragment, obtain `Fragment.SavedState` via `FragmentManager` and save it temporary in `Activity` which hosts your fragments. Note, this state can be lost if you do not properly save Activity state due of configuration changes (rotate) = you have to override also `onSaveInstanceState`in `Activity`. Or simply save `Fragment.SavedState` in global scope (some static field, or in `Application`).

When navigating back to previous fragment, re-create fragment from `Fragment.SavedState` i. e. invoke `Fragment#setInitialSavedState(Fragment.SavedState)`.

For more details see my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282755/how-to-store-restore-activity-state-when-moving-navigating-back) on similar topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a the singleton pattern to store the data!

E.g.

// DataManager.java

```
public class DataManager {
    private static DataManager thisInstance;

    // Declare instance variables
    List<String> searchResultItems;

    public static DataManager getSharedInstance() {
        if (thisInstance == null) {
            thisInstance = new DataManager();
        }
        return thisInstance;
    }

    private DataManager() {
        searchResultItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<String> getSearchResultItems() {
        return searchResultItems;
    }

    public void setSearchResultItems(List<String> searchResultItems) {
        this.searchResultItems = searchResultItems;
    }
}
```

Now you can store and retrive data from everywhere:

// Setter

```
DataManager.getSharedInstance().setSearchResultItems(items);
```

// Getter

```
List<String> items= DataManager.getSharedInstance().getSearchResultItems();
```