# interact togglebutton with textviews in two separate fragments

Tags: android

I have two weeks trying to find a solution on how to resolve the last step.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTz9b.jpg
I add tickets (1 ticket 15 numbers) in database and than show in list view in fragment one, I want that when I check the toggle button in fragment two, for example 8, the text view 8 in tickets fragment change style. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "SharedPreference" you achieve that. When toggle is true, save a value on a SharedPreference, then check in other fragment if that value exist or not. If true and matches the value, then you do wherever you want.

You could also remove the Shared if toggle is false to avoid problems.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: Here is how to save and retrieve: [Save SharedPreference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3624311/3743245) and here is an example of how to remove it: [Remove SharedPreference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3687333/3743245)