# android -remove the entire contents of Shared_Prefs folder in user sandbox

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How do i clear the entire shared preferences folder in the users sandbox not just default. The shared_pref folder is located here usually from adb shell:

```
/data/data/yourappsPackage/shared_prefs
```

So i have created many different shared prefs xml files.

for example i created them like this:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("pref_file1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
context.getSharedPreferences("pref_file2",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
context.getSharedPreferences("pref_file3",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now i would like to clear them all with a single command ? This is what i have tried so far:
`sharedPreferences.editor.clear() ;` but doesn't this only clear the file that im currently using ?

I've tried:

```
preference=context.getSharedPreferences("pref_file1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().clear().commit();
```

and pref_file1 gets cleared but i need pref_file2 and pref_file3 to get cleared also.

Comment: Actually a `clear()` will remove them all.  The `remove()` command is for specific preferences.

Comment: no , i jus tried it and clear removes all per file. I want to remove ALL files.

Comment: No need to do it by a specific sharedPreference.  Get a hold of your shared preferences referenced by your application.  `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`  Then you can call clear on your preferences at this level.

Comment: Jay, i tried your solution on nexus 4 api 19 and it does not clear all the files in shared_pref. It only clears the default file.  Did you actually try it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences

Comment: @j2emanue I did not do a thorough test looking back at it.  Ali seems to be on the best track that I can think of.  Hopefully you don't have to do this on hundreds of files or you will take some serious hits working with preferences in this manner, heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedPreferece is file, so behave it like file. Delete them by below function

```
void delSharedPref(){

File list = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs");
        File[] files = list.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ){
            files[i].delete();
        }

}
```

**Or**

If you search about less code line use below code

```
File s = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs");
s.delete();
s.mkdir();
```

Comment: Thanks i thought of this way. this might be the only answer but i'll wait a few hours and see if anyone else a solution with less lines. Thanks.