# Delete sharedpreferences on click button fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I wanted delete or reset value 0 once user click on reset button ,

here is code which i am using , but seem not be work ..

What wrong I am doing , i am not able to figure out , ..I also tried all way , using google to figure it out , but still stuck.

```
sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(1);


                    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("ccs11").commit();
                    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("spinner_paneer").commit();
```

Below is my fragment , on which i am trying to implement .

```
    public PlanFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gain, container, false);
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(1);



        String cp1s11=sharedPreferences.getString("cp111", "0");
        String cf1s11=sharedPreferences.getString("cf111", "0");
        String ccs11=sharedPreferences.getString("cc111", "0");




        //Button

        btnfinish=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.finish_gain);
        btnfinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(1);
                edt = sharedPreferences.edit();

                edt.putString("ccs11", pro11.getText().toString());





                edt.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }


        });

        btnreset=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.reset);
        btnreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(1);


                sharedPreferences.edit().remove("ccs11").commit();
                sharedPreferences.edit().remove("spinner_paneer").commit();

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting shared preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences)

Comment: I tried using that post only , but it does not work for me