# Use of Shared Preferences and Intent - Setup and Settings application

Tags: android

I am currently developing an application that on the first time the application opens, shows the setup interface and the succeeding times the application is opened, it shows the settings interface. The way I achieved this is that once my application opens, it checks if the shared preferences is null. If the shared preferences is null, it means it was the first time that the application is opened and it will set a value in the shared preferences. Then the next time that the application is opened, when the shared preferences is checked, it isn't null anymore and will go to the settings interface. The problem is, When I run it the first time, it only shows a white screen with no status bar or anything. Below are code snippets of my application

```
 private void saveSharedPref()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    //Save values from Edit Text Controls
    editor.putString("firstTime", "1234");
    editor.commit();
}

private void loadSharedPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE, 0);

    //Null check in case file does not exist
    if(preferences != null) {
        String checkFirst = preferences.getString("firstTime", "");
        if (!checkFirst.equalsIgnoreCase("1234"))
        {
            Intent sendToSetup = new Intent (this, Setup.class);
            startActivity(sendToSetup);
        }
        else
        {
            saveSharedPref();
        }
    }
}
```

I call loadSharedPreferences() in my onCreateMethod

```
public class Setup extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup_pg1);
}
```

This is where the app gets redirected when the user open it for the first time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
P.S. sorry if my english isnt good

EDIT:
here's the androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SafeSwipe"
        android:label="SafeSwipe-UI v.2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Setup" />
</application>
```

setup_pg1

```
<TextView
    android:text="Setup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:text="Continue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:id="@+id/button7" />
```

setup file

```
public class Setup extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup_pg1);
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to show more information.  If you could, please post your  android manifest, and R.layout.setup_pg1

Comment: @user3331142 edited the question

Comment: `getSharedPreferences` can never return `null`, by the way. It will always return a valid object. However it can be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `if(preferences != null)` will never be true because you'll always get a non-null value from `getSharedPreferences()`

> I call loadSharedPreferences() in my onCreate Method

No you don't... here's your code

> ```
> public class Setup extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.setup_pg1);
>     }
> }
> ```

Try again. But use a boolean value rather than some random string.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final String KEY_FIRST_TIME = "firstTime";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
       super.onCreate(b);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       boolean firstTime = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME, false);

       if (!firstTime) {
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
           editor.putBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME, true);
           editor.commit();    
       } else {
           Intent sendToSetup = new Intent (this, Setup.class);
           startActivity(sendToSetup);
           finish();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! settings.edit(); is getting an error. I cant seem to figure out what is this line

Answer (score 0):

Your `if(preferences != null)`is not working here, cause preferences is not null. It's just an empty preference. You can try out the below code:

```
private void loadSharedPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String checkFirst = preferences.getString("firstTime", "");
    if(!checkFirst.equals("")) {        
        Intent sendToSetup = new Intent (this, Setup.class);
        startActivity(sendToSetup);
    }
    else
    {
        saveSharedPref();
    }
}
```

`saveSharedPref()` method:

```
private void saveSharedPref()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    //Save values from Edit Text Controls
    preferences.edit().putString("firstTime", "1234").apply();

}
```

Call `loadSharedPreferences()` in `onCreate()` of Setup Activity:

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where are you calling loadSharedPreferences() ? Please show Setup xml code.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: `preferences.contains` seems pointless. `preferences.getString("firstTime", "")` would return an empty string if the key doesn't exist

Comment: @cricket_007 Why pointless ? Please explain. It looks lot simpler than getting a string then check if it is empty.

Comment: Because `getString` will fallback to the default, which you compare against `1234`

Comment: @OrbadiahKrockenberger Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @tahsinRupam now when I first open the app, white screen shows then after a few seconds, goes to the homescreen for the settings

Comment: It always shows white screen when the app runs for the first time (In my case always this happens and I've started to take it normally :p ). Previously I searched how to avoid this but couldn't find any solution. If it really bothers you, you can ask about this to experts here or in separate question. Other than this, is everything working (SharedPreferences issue) fine ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam it still doesnt. the thing with the white screen only happens on the first time I open the app. On the next runs, it doesnt appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Instead of checking preferences != null try this..

```
if (preferences.getString("firstTime","").equals("1234"))
{
     Intent sendToSetup = new Intent (this, Setup.class);
     startActivity(sendToSetup);
}
else
     saveSharedPref();
```

Comment: Have you initialized the preferences object? I mean preferences = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Mode)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any crucial problem in this code. But I have some assumption that you have already called the `saveSharedPref()` method while testing your program and value of `firstTime` is already exist. Because SharedPreferences are not deleted after recompiling the program this statement:

```
if (!checkFirst.equalsIgnoreCase("1234"))
```

gives false.
The best way to check this is to set a breakpoint in `loadSharedPreferences()` method and verify it.
If it is so try to remove sharedPreferences (see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3687333/7677939 )

or simply give another file name in `SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE` variable.

Also it can be a problem in place where you call `loadSharedPreferences()`, but I cannot see it in your source.

**Update:**
 Notice, that you **should not call** `loadSharedPreferences()` in `Setup` activity, you should call it in your Main activity!