# Clear application shared preference programmatically?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, reset

I'm creating an application in which I have used shared preferences, for testing purpose I have to swipe out that data (preferences) so, how could I clear shared preferences in Android programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a `commit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
context.getSharedPreferences("PREF", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: Please add some more context to this answer so the OP understands the solution. E.g. "What are the 'PREF' and '0' arguments?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear(); 
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the preferences `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear().apply()` 
Check the same question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences).