# Deleting all SharedPreferences upon logout

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want my application to delete all preferences when the user logs out and bring up the `LoginActivity` after exiting the main screen. I've been following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences). In my way, I get only the default preferences.

The workflow of my app goes this way if it helps:

Login -> Save User Details to Preferences -> Start `MainActivity` -> Logout -> Clear Preferences -> Start `LoginActivity`

Is the problem caused by using the default preferences? Or is it because I called finish()? I've tried `apply()` and `commit()`. Neither worked. The preferences still exist when I tried accessing them in the `LoginActivity`. How do I clear my preferences?

```
private void logout(){
    // clear preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i); // call LoginActivity and finish this one.
    finish();
}
```

Comment: what is your question exactly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences)

Comment: @Qasim I'm wondering why my preferences won't clear.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 I mentioned that I've tried that post. It didn't work though.

Comment: problem is that you are not clearing the exact preference file

Comment: @DonovanKeating You need to add how you are creating preference file and how are you reading it. What makes you think that shared preference is not clear. There may be chances in reading the preference i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are using `getPreferences()` instead of `getSharedPreferences()` or `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

> `getPreferences()` Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing
>   preferences that are private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying `ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(String, int)` method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

Since, `getPreferences()` uses class name as it's preference file name, thus you are inserting in one Activity pref file, and clearing another one.

See this for more detail: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getPreferences(int)

Comment: This worked! Thanks man! I shouldn't have been using getPreferences() for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Use commit

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  getSharedPreferences("YourKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: How is this diffferent from OP question

Comment: @Killer refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference

Comment: Alright, you are pointing out apply v/s commit issue. I think an explanation would be nice. Plus i am not sure this the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a library like [Easy Prefs](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPrefs) to handle Sharedprefrences.
It has a method `Prefs.clear()` so basically this would clear all the shared prefs.
This would make it pretty easy for you to handle sharedPrefs.

Alternatively you can clear sharedpref by the following function-:

```
public void clearPrefs(){
    SharedPreferences mySPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySPrefs.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
```