# unset session android in class

Tags: java, android, class, session

I have a file class the name is **Session.java**
then I want create method for destroy session 
how to make it destroy session inside the method ?

```
public class Session {
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public Session(Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    }

    public String setusename(String userid) {
        prefs.edit().putString("userid", userid).commit();
        return userid;
    }

    public String getusename() {
        String userid = prefs.getString("userid","");
        return userid;
    }


}
```

thank you for attention

Comment: you mean to remove userid from shared pref?

Comment: @AndroidUser yes that's true

Comment: make a method some thing like clearUserId and code will be some thing like SharedPreferences.Editor editor_prefs;   editor_prefs = prefs.edit();
                editor_prefs.remove( "userid");
                editor_prefs.apply();
                editor_prefs.commit();

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687315/deleting-shared-preferences

Comment: @AndroidUser ok i will try it thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

```
public class Session {

 // Declare variable.

 Context context;
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 public static String PREF_NAME = "My_Pref";
 public static int PREF_MODE = 0;
 SharedPreferences prefs;

  public Session(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PREF_MODE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
  }

  public String setusename(String userid) {
        editor.putString("userid", userid);
        editor.commit();
        return userid;
    }

    public String getusename() {
        return prefs.getString("userid",null);
    }

//Method for destroy session given below.

public void destroySession() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Call this method in Activity like this,

```
 Session session= new Session(getContext());
```

//For Setting UseId

```
session.setusename("your id");
```

//For Destroying Session

```
  session.destroySession();
```

Comment: should I remove this line 
" prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx); " ?

Comment: I edited my answer , please replace this with your Session class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another method called clearSession for destroy the session

```
public class Session {
  private SharedPreferences prefs;

  public Session(Context cntx) {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
  }

  public String setusename(String userid) {
      prefs.edit().putString("userid", userid).commit();
      return userid;
  }

  public String getusename() {
      String userid = prefs.getString("userid","");
      return userid;
  }

  public void clearSession() {
      // This will clear the session for all values
      prefs.edit().clear();
      prefs.edit().commit();
  }

}
```